# What should `intmax_t` be on platform with 64-bit `long int` and `long long int`?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

In the C++ standard 18.4 it specifies:

```
typedef 'signed integer type' intmax_t;
```

By the standard(s) on a platform with a 64-bit `long int` and a 64-bit `long long int` which should this "signed integer type" be?

Note that `long int` and `long long int` are *distinct* fundamental types.

The C++ standard says:

> The header defines all functions, types, and macros the same as 7.18 in the C standard.

and in 7.18 of the C standard (N1548) it says:

> The following type designates a signed integer type capable of representing any value of
>   any signed integer type:
>
> ```
> intmax_t
> ```

It would seem that in this case that both `long int` and `long long int` qualify?

Is that the correct conclusion?  That either would be a standard-compliant choice?

Comment: just curious, does N1548/7.18 explicitly guarantee that `intmax_t` is a typedef of an existing type rather than a new one? (it seems like it would always be, but can't tell if it's written that way from your quote)

Comment: @StephenLin: You're thinking of `typdef __int128 intmax_t`.  I'm not sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. Most real-world implementations choose the lowest-rank type satisfying the conditions.

Comment: Do you know the rationale for choosing the lowest-rank type satisfying the conditions rather than the highest-rank type?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I would speculate the policy is to choose `long int` if possible because it predates `long long int`, but this is just a wild guess.

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming the GNU C library is correct (from /usr/include/stdint.h):

```
/* Largest integral types.  */
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef long int                intmax_t;
typedef unsigned long int       uintmax_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef long long int           intmax_t;
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uintmax_t;
#end
```